# Why gcloud preview app deploy don't update my app?

Tags: gcloud, google-managed-vm

I can deploy a new app with 'gcloud preview app deploy' but if I change some code and deploy again I can't see the changes on my .appspot.com

'git push origin master' don't work too

I'm using nodejs and google cloud shell inside browser.

Comment: Does the output `gcloud preview app deploy` indicate any errors? Are you sure you're pushing to the correct project and the correct module?

Comment: No errors. I deploy, change code, commit, push, deploy again in same shell. I tried deploy with a version name and the new version is published (default) with old files. I just have 3 files: app.js, app.yaml, package.json. First deploy works. Second deploy dont update code.

Comment: Can u tell me exact steps you use to do this? First deploy, change code, second deploy.

Comment: A number of issues could be present.  It is possible that your second deployment has a different version name or has the same version name.  Traffic may or may not be routed the same way.  Also, as mentioned by Justin, it's possible the second deployment is not sent any traffic.  Lastly, unless you're using some continuous integration tool, committing to a git repository will make no difference.  Only deployments and code changes are meaningful to test this.  Please provide the full deploy command you're using and its console output so we can be confident in the answers we give.

Comment: In addition, depending on your caching rules and headers, it is possible that intermediate caches are serving older content from your application though I would suggest ruling out the above possibilities first.

Answer (score 2):

Until recently, every time you ran `gcloud preview app deploy` we would create a new version of your app, but NOT direct traffic to it from yourapp.appspot.com.  Instead, it would site behind a version number like newversion123.yourapp.appspot.com.

Try updating to the latest version of the Google Cloud SDK by running:

`gcloud components update`

Then try deploying again.  If that doesn't work, try running deploy with --promote:

`gcloud preview app deploy --promote`

If all that fails - please give us the full output of the deploy command :)

Hope this helps!